# json success function not executing

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am trying to post value of an input box and a obtain value of the checked radio button and perform a query based on which radio button is checked ... but my success function is not executing...

**Html form :**

```
     <form class="form-inline" id="myForm">
     <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="title1" name="title" value="title"> 
    Title
    </label>

    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="author" name="title" value="author">
    Author
    </label>

    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="subject" name="title" value="subject"> 
    Subject
    </label><br>

    <input type="text" name="input"> </input>

    <button class="btn btn-inverse" id="download"  >Go</button>
    </form>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('input[name=title]:first').attr('checked', true);

$('#download').click(function(){
    value = $('input[name=title]:checked', '#myForm').val();
    alert(value);

    var input = $('#input').attr('value');
    dataString = 'title='+ value +'&input='+input;
    wurl = "downloadE.php";
    $.ajax({url: wurl, type: "POST",dataType: "json",data:dataString ,success: function(data){

        alert("success");

        }
    })
})
});
```

**php code:**

```
$value = $_POST['title'];
$output = $_POST['input'];
if($value=="title")
{
$query = " select * from library where Title = '$output'; ";
}
else if($value=="author")
{
$query = " select * from library where Author = '$output'; ";
}
else if($value=="subject")
{
$query = " select * from library where Subject = '$output'; ";
}

$result = mysql_query($query);

$ret = array();
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
$ret[] = $info;
}
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: Is your PHP page being invoked? If so, does it execute/complete successfully? If so, does the result make it back to the browser (you can check the traffic in the network tab of your browser's debugging tools)?

Answer (score 1):

When I encounter these types of issues, I'll add an error function and output the details to the console log so that it will help figure out the error. Like so:

```
,success: function(data){
    alert("success");
},error: function(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var callback = function( resp ) {
  alert(123);
}

$.post(url, data, callback, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" name="input"> </input>`

is wrong, and you're missing an ID I believe:

`<input type="text" name="input" id="input" />`

You also need to check that your script is executing. If nothing is being return in your JavaScript it means that the script is failing on the server side.